# How to query two collections from Mongodb in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, aggregate

I have VisitModel that has saved the visit of various users to different visiter locations.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb5d748b8c8a07fee6b4437"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ctopamount" : NumberInt(500), 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(200900410), 
    "lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2018-10-04T09:03:04.619+0000"), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413394574", 
    "name" : "Hirdesh Sharma", 
    "simInventory" : NumberInt(10), 
    "ssa" : "cojp", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "7597000662", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.9140156", 
        "lng" : "75.7997062"
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb5ea682b955e0961e55b24"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ctopamount" : NumberInt(10), 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(200900410), 
    "lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2018-10-04T10:24:40.180+0000"), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413394574", 
    "name" : "Hirdesh Sharma", 
    "simInventory" : NumberInt(10), 
    "ssa" : "cojp", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "7597000662", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.9140203", 
        "lng" : "75.7997103"
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb71766edeebb1682902c5a"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ctopamount" : NumberInt(0), 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(200900410), 
    "lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2018-10-05T07:48:54.566+0000"), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413394574", 
    "name" : "Hirdesh Sharma", 
    "simInventory" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ssa" : "cojp", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "123456789", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.913970499999998", 
        "lng" : "75.799515"
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb71991edeebb1682902c5b"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ctopamount" : NumberInt(0), 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(200900410), 
    "lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2018-10-05T07:58:09.241+0000"), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413394574", 
    "name" : "Hirdesh Sharma", 
    "simInventory" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ssa" : "cojp", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "1234567890", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.9140163", 
        "lng" : "75.7997024"
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb72c28edeebb1682902c5d"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ctopamount" : NumberInt(10000), 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(200901869), 
    "lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2018-10-05T09:17:28.825+0000"), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413395846", 
    "name" : "Dharmendra Soni", 
    "simInventory" : NumberInt(15), 
    "ssa" : "Circle Office", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "0000000000", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.8922714", 
        "lng" : "75.8042042"
    }
}


// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb72e50edeebb1682902c5e"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ctopamount" : NumberInt(5000), 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(200901869), 
    "lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2018-10-05T09:26:40.371+0000"), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413395846", 
    "name" : "Dharmendra Soni", 
    "simInventory" : NumberInt(10), 
    "ssa" : "Circle Office", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "9414002070", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.8922503", 
        "lng" : "75.8041773"
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb72f49edeebb1682902c5f"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ctopamount" : 1.5, 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(200901869), 
    "lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2018-10-05T09:30:49.843+0000"), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413395846", 
    "name" : "Dharmendra Soni", 
    "simInventory" : null, 
    "ssa" : "Circle Office", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "7597000559", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.8922608", 
        "lng" : "75.8041638"
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb759e7edeebb1682902c63"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ctopamount" : NumberInt(0), 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(198911286), 
    "lastUpdationTime" : ISODate("2018-10-05T12:32:39.394+0000"), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413395614", 
    "name" : "Shankara lal meena", 
    "simInventory" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ssa" : "Chittorgarh", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "7597000559", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "24.038592", 
        "lng" : "74.7767928"
    }
}
}
```

i have another model which has a saved database of RetailerLocation which has saved the filed retailer name ,address ,retailer number and a location

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a029"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "Karan Singh", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.8122376, 
        "lng" : 75.7783984
    }, 
     "Retailernumber"  : "7597000559"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a02a"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "HANUMAN PRASAD", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.9142872, 
        "lng" : 75.7431824
    }, 
     "Retailernumber"  : "7597000632"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a02b"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "Karan Singh", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.9039945, 
        "lng" : 75.8325143
    }, 
     "Retailernumber"  : "7597000633"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a02c"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "kunal hemani", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.931319, 
        "lng" : 75.8201112
    }, 
    "Retailernumber" : "7597000638"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a02d"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "kumawat floor mill", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.8592253, 
        "lng" : 75.7851659
    }, 
    "Retailernumber": "7597000662"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a02e"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "care point", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.9247296, 
        "lng" : 75.7894896
    }, 
    "Retailernumber" : "7597000708"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a02f"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "SAYED MOBILE", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.933338, 
        "lng" : 75.8074372
    }, 
    "Retailernumber" : "7597000718"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a030"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "jaipur moters", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.9187819, 
        "lng" : 75.8102266
    }, 
    "Retailernumber" : "7597000773"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a031"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "sona telecom", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
    "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.9212756, 
        "lng" : 75.8085795
    }, 
    "Retailernumber" : "7597000776"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a032"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "sangam mobile", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
   "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.9194859, 
        "lng" : 75.8078163
    }, 
    "Retailernumber" : "7597000785"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c864a80498ceb2d94a8a033"), 
    "Name of Retailer" : "bombay  collection", 
    "SSA" : "JAIPUR", 
   "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : 26.8564543, 
        "lng" : 75.8207683
    }, 
   "Retailernumber": "7597000792"
}
```

now i want to display the data as following

```
{
    "ctopamount" : NumberInt(500), 
    "hrno" : NumberInt(200900410), 
    "mobileNo" : "9413394574", 
    "name" : "Hirdesh Sharma", 
    "simInventory" : NumberInt(10), 
    "ssa" : "cojp", 
    "visitedRetailer" : "7597000662", 
    "visitLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.9140156", 
        "lng" : "75.7997062"
    }
  "savedLocation" : {
        "lat" : "26.9140156", 
        "lng" : "75.7997062"
    }
}
```

where the saved location should be fetched from RetailerLocation collection based on `visitedRetailer=RetailerMobile`

Answer (score 0):

In your visit model instead of saving the visit location, you can directly save the object id of the retailers from the retailer location. Then you can just use the populate the data. Here is the reference to the populate in [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Now i cant change the document design. Any solution with existing collection please.One more thing in visit model the location being saved is fetched from mobile gps while the location form retailer location is a  reference location.So that i can compare the distance in these two location.Thanks for your prompt reply

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

Write aggregate function in visitModel and lookup to RetailerLocation.

Test1 -> visitModel
Test2 ->RetailerLocation

```
db.getCollection('Test1').aggregate([
{
$lookup:{
    from:"Test2",
    localField:"visitedRetailer",
    foreignField:"Retailernumber",
    as:"retailerDetails"
    }
},
{
$unwind:{
    path:"$retailerDetails",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
    }
},
{
$project:{
            "ctopamount" :1, 
            "hrno" : 1, 
            "mobileNo" : 1, 
            "name" : 1, 
            "simInventory" :1, 
            "ssa" : 1, 
            "visitedRetailer" : 1, 
            "visitLocation" : 1,
            "savedLocation" : "$retailerDetails.savedLocation"
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks madhav this worked but.can we use the same in node.js using mongoose

Comment: Sorry brother. I am not familiar with mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to comment but with respect to @Ashwanth Madhav 's answer, you can do the same in mongoose.

```
Test1.aggregate([{
$lookup:{
from:"Test2",
localField:"visitedRetailer",
foreignField:"Retailernumber",
as:"retailerDetails"
}
},
{
$unwind:{
path:"$retailerDetails",
preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
}
},
{
$project:{
        "ctopamount" :1, 
        "hrno" : 1, 
        "mobileNo" : 1, 
        "name" : 1, 
        "simInventory" :1, 
        "ssa" : 1, 
        "visitedRetailer" : 1, 
        "visitLocation" : 1,
        "savedLocation" : "$retailerDetails.savedLocation"
}}
                ]).exec(function (err,fetcheddata) {

    if( _.isNull(err) && fetcheddata.length > 0 ){
        var response = genRes.generateResponse(true,"found successfully");
        callback(response,fetcheddata);
    }
    else if( fetcheddata==undefined || transactions.length == 0 ){
        var response = genRes.generateResponse(false,"No Data found");
        callback(response,null);
    }
    else{
        var response = genRes.generateResponse(false,"there occurred some error : "+err);
        callback(response,null)
    }
})
};
```